# Serialize and deserialize multiple objects using DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer

How do I serialize and deserialize multiple objects using DataContractSerializer?
Serializing is fine, however during deserialization I get the error

"The serialization operation failed. Reason: There was an error deserializing the object of type Serialization.Person. There are multiple root elements."

The error message clearly mentions that there is no root element to the serialized document.
But how do i overcome this?

Here's the code:

```
[DataContract]
class Person {
    [DataMember(Name = "CustName")]
    internal string Name;
    public Person(string n) {Name = n;}
}

class Program {
    public static void Main() {
            WriteObject("d:\\temp\\DataContractExample.xml" , "Mary");
            WriteObject("d:\\temp\\DataContractExample.xml", "Joe");
            ReadObject("d:\\temp\\DataContractExample.xml");
    }

    public static void WriteObject(string path, string name) {
        Person p1 = new Person(name);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append);
        XmlDictionaryWriter writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(fs);
        DataContractSerializer ser =  new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Person));
        ser.WriteObject(writer, p1);

        writer.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
    public static void ReadObject(string path) {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        XmlDictionaryReader reader =
            XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(fs, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());

        DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Person));

        // Deserialize the data and read it from the instance.
        Person[] newPerson = (Person[])ser.ReadObject(reader);
        Console.WriteLine("Reading this object:");
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", newPerson[0].Name));
        fs.Close();
    }
```

When I read from the DataContractSerializer, ser.ReadObject(reader), I get the exception that I mentioned above.
Is it possible to Create root element while storing multiple objects using DataContractSerializer?

Comment: If the storage format can be changed, though, then note that some formats are safely appendable; let me know if you might be interested in a similar example using a different data format (but which works)

Comment: Note also - you are *writing* (separately) two `Person` instances, and trying to deserialize a `Person[]` - but that has a very different layout

Comment: Yes Marc! What other storage formats are you talking about. Any pointers will help me. I am creating a storage solution for a workflow hierarchy. So I need to dynamically append, modify and delete elements.

Comment: appending is easy; modifying and deleting from the middle of a file generally means re-writing the entire file

Comment: Note: if you can serialize a `List<Person>` in the first place, this may be a non-issue (i.e. it'll work with DataContractSerializer)

Comment: I downloaded the protobuf from google code; however while calling Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix, I get this exception : "{"The type initializer for 'ProtoBuf.SerializerProxy`1' threw an exception."}" InnerException : "{"Only data-contract classes (and lists/arrays of such) can be processed (error processing Person)"}"

Comment: was that the same code I posted? 'cos the code I posted works just fine with v2 r450. It *should* work with v1 too (haven't checked)

Comment: serializing as a List<Person> works just fine too!!

Comment: using DataContractSerializer, right? if so, I'll remove the other stuff from my answer, to avoid future confusion

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4422/discussion-between-santhosh-and-marc-gravell)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DataContractSerializer` works on xml documents, so expects a single top-level element. The simplest approach would be to serialize a `List<Person>`, which should avoid this. You could also add an outer element manually, perhaps using `XmlReader` and `ReadSubtree` during serialization (although note: this is ugly hard work).

The simplest option, though, is to simply serialize a `List<Person>` from the outset, and deserialize as a `List<Person>` - this will then be a *single* xml hunk, so won't upset the deserializer.